# Questions that Ask to Verify Solution to Problem

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, solution-verification

Is it okay to ask questions where you give the solution and ask people to review it to see if it is correct?

Comment: Previously: [Are “please check my proof” type of questions proper?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1878/856), [Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4597/856) (and, well, there's also [Would a tag for “check-my-proof” questions be useful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6636/856))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Yes...](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=yes+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: Search results for ["verification" on meta.MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=verification) .

Answer (score 6):

Why not? This question of mine, [How do I prove that $\det A= \det A^t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298583/how-do-i-prove-that-det-a-det-at) led to an interesting discussion. I could not only verify my solution but I could also grab a few interesting ideas.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely ok for me. After all, we *want* the askers to show their own efforts they have put into the problem so far. If it turns out that their effort was good enough to be a complete solution, even better as they show they did not simply lose hope right in the beginning.

One might argue that then they should rather ask the original problem question and give their own complete efforts as a self-answer, but apparently they are not really *sure* that their attempt is a valid answer, so this cannot be recommended, just in case the own attempt is wrong or lousy.

Another idea might be to transform

> **Question:** "I am asked to solve *Q*. My answer attempt is *A*, but I am not sure. Is it correct? -- Noob"
>
> **Answer:** "Yes, that's fine. --Expert"

ultimately to

> **Question:** "How to solve *Q*? -- Noob"
>
> **Accepted Answer:** "*A*. --Noob"

but I won't prefer that (even though "Expert" might not be harmed too much by the reputation loss for a simple "Yes")